# Detect when the Swipe Lock has gone

Tags: android, lockscreen

I have a Service that displays a Float Icon over the lock screen. I want to hide the Float Icon immediately when the Swipe Lock goes and the Secure lock appears. Currently, I am listening to the `Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT`, but the system is only send it when the Secure Lock goes!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a broadcast receiver for action :

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
```

Broadcast Receiver :

```
public class SwipeLockMonitorReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT.equalsIgnoreCase(intent
            .getAction())) {
        // Means the swipe lock gone.
    }
}
```

}

Manifest :

```
<receiver android:name="SwipeLockMonitorReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: I have already used that, but like I've mentioned this will only trigger when the Secure Lock goes and this is not what I meant. I want a broadcast the triggers when you Swipe to Unlock and the Lock Screen appears. (I am not sure if I explained it well! Hope you'll get it)

Comment: Can you try with some other devices then?? since I'm having the same requirement of yours and is working perfectly for me.